# What is the JavaScript regex for <br /> when it is HTML encoded?

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the regex for the HTML encoded version of `<br />` in JavaScript:  `&lt;br /&gt;`

```
var edit_text = $(".edit_area").html().trim(),
    regex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;  //This needs replacing

$(".edit_area").html(edit_text.replace(regex, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern won't match encoded `<br>` elements because it has a plain `<` which doesn't match an encoded `&lt;`. Try this to handle html encoded elements:

```
regex = /&lt;br\s*\/?(&gt;|>)/gi;
```

Note that the closing character of a tag doesn't *have* to be encoded, so my pattern handles allows either encoded (`&gt;`) or un-encoded (`>`) closing characters. You can extend this to handle both using a pattern like this:

```
regex = /(&lt;|<)br\s*\/?(&gt;|>)/gi;
```

You can test it out [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%28<%7C%3C%29br%5Cs%2a%5C/?%28>%7C%3E%29&input=this%20%3Cbr/%3E%20is%20<br/%3E%20a%20<br/>%20test).

Comment: @sansix I've included an explanation as well as a demonstration of the code for completeness.

Comment: +1 yeah now it explains things clearly - BTW should we care for this case also ` <br/  >` ?

Comment: I meant space between / and >

Comment: @sansix You need to be able to handle spaces before the `/`, e.g. `<br />`, but I don't think you'd need to worry about a space between the `/` and `>`.  I don't believe `<br/ >` is valid HTML or XHTML. (Of course it's possible OP would want to match that, despite the fact that it's not valid, but that wasn't specified in the question)

Comment: ohhh thanks for that - seems I was getting too much into test cases :)

Comment: @sansix speaking of test cases, it's possible for a `br` element to have attributes, e.g. `<br id="foo" />`, or to be paired `<br></br>`. If you want to handle every possible valid case, it's generally best to actually parse the string as a DOM / XML fragment and then analyze the resulting tree--regular expressions are just not sophisticated enough for most advanced tasks.

Comment: yeah agreed with the points - You cleared my earlier doubts as well as in almost all html-regex questions - experts use to answer "better to parse them than using regex"